# Woocommerce product search in admin is not working

Tags: woocommerce

I have a list of products in woocommerce [image]

when I search for a product (in admin), it always says "No Products found": [image: 2]

This is the URL `/wp-admin/edit.php?s=Deluxe&post_status=all&post_type=product&action=-1&m=0&product_cat&product_type&paged=1&action2=-1`

and when I remove `product_cat` from the URL the product comes up

Comment: I'm having the same issue, although removing product_cat doesn't seem to work. Filtering also is not returning results.  I have the same issue with Orders, but Users search works fine. WC 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Add in the following snippet to `function.php`:

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts' );
function products_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

  if(is_admin()){
     $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'fields' => 'ids' ) )
        )
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After disable the YoastSeo plugin, the search works properly again.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from Chandrakant Devani helped, but broke other searches in the admin. Adding an if seems to avoid breakages

`if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product')`

full code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts' );
function products_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'fields' => 'ids' ) )
            )
        ) );
    }
}
```